# My Java program isn't showing the GUI in the window

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I asked a similar question before, but I am having the problem again with different code. When I run the program, the window pops up, but the `labels`, `textboxes`, and `button` isn't showing. Help will be much appreciated! I am using `Eclipse IDE`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MonthlySalesTax extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;               // A panel to hold everything
    private JTextField totalSales;      // To get total sales
    private JButton calcButton;         // Calculates everything

    // Constants for tax rates
    private final double COUNTY_RATE = 0.02;
    private final double STATE_RATE = 0.04;

    // Constants for window size
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 360;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */

    public MonthlySalesTax() {
        // Set the title.
        setTitle("Monthly Sales Tax Reporter");

        // Specify what happens when the close button is clicked.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Build the panel that contains the other components.
        buildPanel();

        // Size and display the window
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * The buildPanel method creates a panel containing other components.
     */

    private void buildPanel() {

        // Create a label prompting for the total sales.
        JLabel totalSalesMsg = new JLabel("Enter the total sales:");

        //Create a text field for total sales.
        totalSales = new JTextField(10);

        // Create a button to click.
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Sales Tax");

        // Add an action listener to the button.
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());

        // Create a panel.
        panel = new JPanel();

        // Add the label, text field, and button to the panel.
        panel.add(totalSalesMsg);
        panel.add(totalSales);
        panel.add(calcButton);
    }

    /**
     * CalcButtonListener is an action listener class for the calcbutton           component.
     */

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        /**
         * actionPerformed method
         * @param e An ActionEvent object.
         */

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double totalSalesAmount,            // To hold the total sales     amount
                    countyTaxAmount,            // To hold the county tax
                    stateTaxAmount,             // To hold the state tax
                    totalTaxAmount;             // To hold the total tax

            // Create a DecimalFormat object to format output.
            DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

            // Get the total sales.
            totalSalesAmount = Double.parseDouble(totalSales.getText());

            // Calculate the county tax.
            countyTaxAmount = totalSalesAmount * COUNTY_RATE;

            // Calculate the state tax.
            stateTaxAmount = totalSalesAmount * STATE_RATE;

            // Calculate the total sales.
            totalTaxAmount = countyTaxAmount + stateTaxAmount;

            // Display the result.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "County Sales Tax: $" +
                                        dollar.format(countyTaxAmount) +
                                        "\nState Sales Tax: $" +
                                        dollar.format(stateTaxAmount) +
                                        "\nTotal Sales Tax: $" +
                                        dollar.format(totalTaxAmount));
        }
    }

    /**
     * The main method creates an instance of the SalesTax class,
     * causing it to display its window.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MonthlySalesTax stx = new MonthlySalesTax();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you ever add the panel to the JFrame?

Comment: I do not see where you add the `panel` you create in `buildPanel` to the `JFrame`

Comment: You seem to have two questions, similar in problem, about two different bits of code. Did you ever resolve the first problem? If not, then you should pursue one issue at a time and learn from it. If you have resolved it, then you should mark an answer an accepted. As it stands, you seem to be scattergunning your questions. More time thinking, less time asking

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, I meant to delete the other question before I had posted this one. Sorry about that. This one is solved though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I forgot to add the panel to the JFrame as you guys suggested.

was a simple:

```
add(panel);
```

thanks all!